# how can I prevent write and paste special characters inside input fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to prevent inputs from writing and inserting special characters.
This will prevent characters from being written, but will not prevent them from being inserted. How can i do it with JQuery?

```js
 $('#first').keypress(function (e) {
    var txt = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    if (!txt.match(/[A-Za-z0-9&. ]/)) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="form" action="reg.php" method="POST" id="reg" onsubmit="return formSubmit();">
    <input type="text" name="first" id="first" required/>
    <input type="text" name="sec" id="sec" required />
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the below REGEX to prevent from special characters

```
var nospecial=/^[^*|\":<>[\]{}`\\()';@&$]+$/;

$('#first').keypress(function (e) {
    var txt = nospecial.test(e.val());
    if (!txt) {
        $('#first').val('');
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work I can still paste some special character

Comment: Now you can check I added the code to make the input as empty on paste.

Comment: I'd suggest using `input`, not `keypress`, as right now it's trivial to get around this by pasting in with the mouse

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to bind to the `paste` event and run a replace on the string to remove characters you don't want. This example will allow pasting, but will strip out characters that aren't allowed.

#### Solution

```js
$('#first').keypress(function (e) {
  var txt = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
  if (!txt.match(/[A-Za-z0-9&. ]/)) {
      return false;
  }
});

$('#first').bind('paste', function() {
  setTimeout(function() { 
    var value = $('#first').val();
    var updated = value.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9&. ]/g, '');
    $('#first').val(updated);
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="first" />
```

#### Notes

- In the `bind` function, I added `^` to your matching group to match everything that isn't those characters.
- You could update your regular expression to `/a-z0-9&.\s/i`. `\s` means space (it's more readable than an actual space), and `i` means case-insensitive.
- If you want to allow `_` characters, you could use `\w` instead of `A-Za-z0-9`, in which case, you could also use `\W` to match the opposite.

#### Documentation

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/paste

Answer (score 2):

Every key has a unique `keycode`. You should catch the `keycode` and validate them.
[This is a list of codes of keys](https://gist.github.com/tylerbuchea/8011573)

```html
<input type="text" onkeypress="return checkEntry(event)" onpaste="return checkEntry(event)" onchange="return checkEntry(event)">

<script>
  function checkEntry(e) {
    var k;
    document.all ? k = e.keyCode : k = e.which;
    return ((k > 64 && k < 91) || (k > 96 && k < 123) || k == 8 || k == 32 || (k >= 48 && k <= 57));
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Doesn't work I can still paste some special character

Comment: Can you tell what is that special char ?

Comment: For example : & ;

Comment: Nope... Its working fine.. I unable to insert those keys

Comment: Are pasting instead of pressing keys?

Comment: I can paste them into your input. I'm using chrome

Comment: The problem is event Handler.. I catch only press event.. You should change it to onChange

Comment: But if you change it to `onChange` you can write special character

Comment: You have 2 `onkeypress` event handler

Comment: @executable is it bad to have 2 event handlers if it works?

Comment: I mean you can delete a `onkeypress` because it's duplicate

Comment: @executable ooh yes, i see now.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have JQuery here is [input mask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask) plugin for your consideration. You can find demo [here](https://robinherbots.github.io/Inputmask/).

Answer (score 1):

you can try this
and add keys which you want to restrict or dont want to restrict in this specialKeys aaray

```js
var specialKeys = new Array();
specialKeys.push(8); //Backspace
specialKeys.push(9); //Tab
specialKeys.push(46); //Delete
specialKeys.push(36); //Home
specialKeys.push(35); //End
specialKeys.push(37); //Left
specialKeys.push(39); //Right
function IsAlphaNumeric(e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode == 0 ? e.charCode : e.keyCode;
    var ret = ((keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) || (keyCode >= 65 && keyCode <= 90) || (keyCode >= 97 && keyCode <= 122) || (specialKeys.indexOf(e.keyCode) != -1 && e.charCode != e.keyCode));
    document.getElementById("error").style.display = ret ? "none" : "inline";
    return ret;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text1" onkeypress="return IsAlphaNumeric(event);" ondrop="return IsAlphaNumeric(event);" onpaste="return IsAlphaNumeric(event);" />
<span id="error" style="color: Red; display: none">* Special Characters not allowedspan>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use onpaste event..

```
$("#first").onpaste(function () {
   ....
   ....
}
```

Comment: Please add some context to the _code snippet_ for the benefit of the future readers.

Answer (score 0):

In ReactJS we can use the following

```
const checkSpecialChar =(e)=>{
 if(!/[0-9a-zA-Z/.test(e.key)){
  e.preventDefault();
}
}

<input type='text' className='class' onkeyDown={(e)=>checkSpecialChar(e)}/>
```